# Remove data connection of Excel Spreadsheet automatically

Tags: excel

I need to automatize the following operation:

- Open a Excel file at a scheduled time
  (I configured its data connection so that the data automatically gets
  updated)
- Save a Copy of that file, WITHOUT including the data connection.

That report is sent to the customer and therefore can't possible include the query code.

The opening, updating and saving as a copy is not a problem and I will do it with a scripting tool that creates a Windows exe-file that then can be launched at the time I schedule it in Windows TaskScheduler.

But how can I manage to eliminate the data connection?

Regard,
Martin

Comment: Use VBA instead of the scripting tool.

Comment: Does that cover the launching of the file? I don't want Excel to be running all the time? Or does VBA takes over, once the spreadsheet has been opened by the TaskScheduler. Sorry, I'm not an Excel guy and will have to ask my colleague to do the VBA.

Comment: Use a Workbook_Open event, which runs when the file is opened. Then use the scripting tool to open the file and the VBA should run automatically.

Comment: Ok, I followed your advise and it was simpler than I expected

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a Workbook_Open event, which runs when the file is opened. Then use the scripting tool to open the file and the VBA should run automatically.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Excel Interop, you can use this code

```
using Excel = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;

Excel.Application app = new Excel.Application();
app.DisplayAlerts = false;
Excel.Workbook wb = app.Workbooks.Open(filepath);
int count_conn = wb.Connections.Count;
if (count_conn > 0)
{
    for (int i = 1; i <= wb.Connections.Count; i++)
    {
        wb.Connections[i].Delete();
        i = i - 1;
    }
    count_conn = wb.Connections.Count;
    wb.Save(); // Save workbook
}
wb.Save();
wb.Close();
app.Quit();
if (RuntimeInformation.IsOSPlatform(OSPlatform.Windows))
{
    Marshal.ReleaseComObject(wb);
    Marshal.ReleaseComObject(app);
}
```